# can html5 audio streaming be 100 % sync with current device time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I wanted to know if it is possible `HTML5` audio streaming super accurately synced with device current time. 
like I have a 10 minutes of audio file at device time 01:00 audio starts from 00:00 and at 01:05 audio plays at 05:00 and end at 01:10. I mean when ever I click play HTML5 audio player it play the audio according to the current device time.

Here is what I tried but audio is always a little behind the time (in milliseconds).

```js
 var player = document.getElementById('music'); 
player.addEventListener('play', function() { 
            var main_date = new Date();
            var hour = main_date.getUTCHours();
            var minutes = main_date.getUTCMinutes();
            var seconds = main_date.getUTCSeconds();

            var current_second = ( hour * 60 * 60 ) + ( minutes * 60 ) + seconds;
            var audio_start =  current_second%player.duration ;
            player.currentTime = parseInt(audio_start);
        }, false);
        
        player.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgressBar, false);
         
        function updateProgressBar() {
            var percentage = Math.floor((100 / player.duration) * player.currentTime);
 
            var di = document.getElementById('datetime');
            di.innerHTML = new Date() ;
        }
```

```html
<div id="datetime"></div>
<audio controls id="music">
<source src="http://www.easel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/ClAudioSync-599_99seconds_128kbps.mp3">
<audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Web Audio API.

By using WAA you would typically first load the entire sample into memory, then use the [`currentTime`](https://devdocs.io/dom/baseaudiocontext/currenttime) on the `AudioContext` to [schedule](https://devdocs.io/dom/audiobuffersourcenode/start) the sample. Use the offset argument to determine start point in the sample.